# Why does the function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK return the same value?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am doing an opencv application and I am using de LucasKanada algorithm.
I use this function:

```
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(pregray, gray,points[0], points[1], status, err, Size(31,31),3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
```

to calculate the new position of the points, but e.g the point [1][2] has the same value that the point [0][2], not changes. why?

Comment: Please don't post all-cap question titles.

Comment: What is `point`?  Where is it defined, where are you referencing it?

Comment: The value of points [0][0], [0][1] and [0][2] are established on Main, this function only calculate the new positions of these points, and push its news positions in vector points[1][x]

Comment: In general this function does not return the same values for `points[0]` and `points[1]`. I can't answer your question without seeing how you initialize the arguments you supply to the function. My guess is that your `prevgray` image is the same as `gray`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how you initialize the arguments to the function it hard to answer your question. But my guess is that your `prevgray` image is the same as `gray`.

The copy operator (i.e. `=`) for Mat objects will only copy the headers and the pointer to the matrix, not the data itself. If you grab images from the camera make sure you copy the image data. Something like this:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
Mat frame, gray, prevgray;

for(;;)
{
    cap >> frame;
    gray = rgb2gray(frame);

    calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(pregray, gray,points[0], points[1], status, err, 
         Size(31,31),3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);

    gray.copyTo(prevGray);  // make sure you copy the data

    // if you do                       
    // prevgray = gray; 
    // then in the next iteration gray and prevgray will point to the same data 
}
```